# strtotime stopped working with change of new year (2022)

Tags: date-format, strtotime

I have the following piece of code to find next month, if before the 20th, and two months out, if after the 20th.  Then it converts the month number to a character.

Before January 2022 I was able to get the number of the month using

```
$month =  strtotime($current_month);
```

After some searching around I got it working by changing that piece of code to

```
$month = date_format($current_month, 'm');
```

Any help as to why it stopped working or if the ***date_format*** is the proper way to go would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
// get day of month without leading zero
$today = date("j");

//if before 20th get next month, else get two months out
IF ($today < 20) {
    $time =  new DateTime();
    $current_month = $time->modify('+1 months');
}else{  
    $time =  new DateTime();    
    $current_month = $time->modify('+2 months');
}

**//  before January 2022 this worked:  $month =  strtotime($current_month);
//after January 2022 I changed code to this to work
$month = date_format($current_month, 'm');**

    $code = array (
    '01' => 'f',
    '02' => 'g',
    '03' => 'h',
    '04' => 'j',
    '05' => 'k',
    '06' => 'm',
    '07' => 'n',
    '08' => 'q',
    '09' => 'u',
    '10' => 'v',
    '11' => 'x',
    '12' => 'z');

$month_code = $code[$month];
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, please add a tag for the programming language you are using

Comment: The fix is the second code section above:  **$month = date_format($current_month, 'm');**

I posted to find out why, to let other folks know what worked, and to see if _date_format_ has any similar anomolies.

Answer (score 0):

Use `**$month = date_format($current_month, 'm');**`

Instead of `*$month =  strtotime($current_month);*`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Wish I could.  Makes no sense to me why it worked for months and then seemed to stop with the change of the year.